# Idle event not executing after registration and show?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, forms

I have an application where I would like to execute certain orders on a certain thread when that thread is idling. So I created a manager to handle this for me, launched of a form.show and created a thread manager:

```
public class ThreadManager
{
    static List<ThreadAble> orders = new List<ThreadAble>();
    public static bool running = false;
    public static void execute(ThreadAble action)
    {
        orders.Add(action);
    }


    public static void RegisterAPIThreadAndHold()
    {
        running = true;
        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
    }

    private static void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (orders.Count != 0)
        {
            ThreadAble f = orders.First();
            orders.Remove(f);
            f.execute();
        }
    }
}
public interface ThreadAble {
      void execute();        
}
public static class formstuff{
    private static void ShowDialogThreaded(){
        form.Show(owner);                        
        ThreadManager.RegisterAPIThreadAndHold();
        }
     }
 }
```

I then try to use this using it by:

```
   public class TestRegister : ThreadAble
     {
       public void execute()
           {
               throw new NotImplementedException();
           }

    }
   ThreadManager.execute(new TestRegister());
```

Now this should throw an exception, however it doesn't. I have also tried with more complicated behaviour and breakpoints but this code seems to never get executed. Am I misunderstanding how the Application_Idle works? Is there another way to make it so that this thread starts executing my code (has to be this thread) when it's done with handling the GUI code and not doing anything else (it might be required to do other things a well).

I already veritfied that RegisterAPIThreadAndHold() is executed.

Comment: Maybe the application message queue is not emptying (although CPU usage does go down), how do I check that?